# valgrind determine which unrecognised instruction

Tags: valgrind, wine

I've been trying to debug a windows game running on Linux (Arch) using wine. I've managed to make the game run but there is a 80% CPU load in idle (login screen), which seems a bit excessive and thus I would like to try and reduce that. So naturally my first step is to try the callgrind tool from the valgrind suite to try to determine where the program spends most of its time so I can narrow down where the issue may be.

I have followed the recommendations from https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_and_Valgrind . However valgrind seems to stop with the following error message

```
vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF2 0xC3 0x8B 0x4D
==358649== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0xb478a4.
==358649==    at 0xB478A4: ???
```

After some online searching and other similar questions here I found that valgrind does not support `SSE4, AVX, AVX2` on `x86` https://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html . So I then compiled wine myself from source using the extra compiler flags `-mno-sse4 -mno-sse4a -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mno-avx -mno-avx2 -O0 -g` in an effort to disable these instructions. However when I try to run valgrind again but this time using this newly compiled executable I get the exact same error message

```
vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF2 0xC3 0x8B 0x4D
==361135== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0xb478a4.
==361135==    at 0xB478A4: ???
```

So my guess is that that this instruction at `0xF2 0xC3 0x8B 0x4D` is not one that I disabled. How do I determine which specific CPU instruction corresponds to the bytes `0xF2 0xC3 0x8B 0x4D`? So I can try to disable this instruction in gcc in order to be able to run valgrind to analyze my program, or perhaps you guys have different ideas of things I could try?

Comment: Running Valgrind with vgdb and getting gdb to disassemble is your best bet. Otherwise try online dissassemblers or objdump.